# How to access css selector properties after getting access to selector

Tags: javascript, css

```
.test
{
 color:Red;
 width: 100px;
}

   var r = document.styleSheets[index].rules;   

   r[0].selectorText => Here we get ".test";
```

Now i want to get access of all .test properties (in this case color and width) in an array and its values ( in this case Red & 100px ).How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `.cssText` of the CSSStyleRule. (You can find this yourself with `console.log(document.styleSheets[2])` on this page and diving through the items in the console of Chrome or Firebug.)

Also note that while `.rules` works in some browsers, the [DOM Level 2 CSS binding](http://objjob.phrogz.net/css/object/233) is `.cssRules`.

**Edit**: If you need access to individual styles, then use the `.style` property. Again, you could see if this you used the developer console.

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[2];
var rules = sheet.cssRules[1];
console.log( rules ); // Lots of properties
console.log( Object.keys(rules) );
// ["parentRule", "cssText", "type", "selectorText", "style", "parentStyleSheet"]
console.log( rules.style.display ); // "none"
```

If you want to see *just* the styles that are applied in this rule, you'll have to either iterate through the properties of the `.style` collection (which includes properties that were not explicitly set) and check for empty values, or else you'll need to parse the cssText yourself.

Comment: Doesn't .cssText only apply to embedded css?

Comment: @Mathachew Not sure what you mean. On this page `document.styleSheets[2].cssRules[1].cssText #=> "#adzerk2, #adzerk2 + div { display: none !important; }"`

Comment: thanks for ans but this return all (just like innerhtml of any element) but i want it individualy like a array, like array[0] = color, array[1] = width

Comment: @Phrogz I had this mixed up with something I was working on the other night and .cssText wasn't reliable. However, I wasn't aware of document.styleSheets and was instead trying to pull straight from an element with mixed results between IE and Chrome. Edit: this is what I was referring to: http://jsfiddle.net/Ur474/1/

Comment: How can i iterate all properties of .style collection

Comment: @gaurav Using `var propNames=Object.keys(foo.style)` on newer browsers or a standard `for (var propName in foo.style)` loop for all.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery makes this easy.

```
$('.test').each(function(){
    var curColor = $(this).css('color');
    // etc
});
```

Comment: That would fail as this is the DOM element and not a jQuery element thus css is not defined.

Comment: It would work just fine. `this` is a jQuery element in the current scope.

Comment: No it isn't just look at the error in the console on this http://jsfiddle.net/bMS7D/1/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/ "More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element."

Comment: but .test is in css file and we are reading it from there r[0].seletorText = ".test"

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake should be `$(this)`.